# Not able to view Google (red)pin in recorded test script IBM Mobilefirst TestWorkbench 8.6.0.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

Tool: IBM MobileFirst Test Workbench 8.6.0.1
OS: Windows 7

Scenario: In MobileFirst app, have a "Get Place" button. On click of this button a input box pops up.
Enter the placename in input box and hit search, the location is shown in app(Google map background) with a red pin on it. Click the red pin to get details of the location.

Record the above scenario in MTW. Open the recorded script. Go to the step "Click on the red pin". In *Screen Capture* view the red pin does not show up.

The red pin is not captured in recorded test. Any suggestions how to resolve above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using MobileFirst Test Workbench with Google Maps is not a supported path. This cannot be done.